# IMAP configs for Outlook using Mail-listener

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, imap, node-imap

I would like to know if there are any other options in mailbox other than **INBOX** for example SPAM or Junk Emails for Microsoft Outlook?
Currently I am using Mail-listener for IMAP connection and here is the following code

```
configs = {
      host: "outlook.office365.com",
      username: "",
      password: "",
      port: 993,
      tls: true,
      mailbox: "INBOX",
      searchFilter: ["NEW"],
      markSeen: false,
      fetchUnreadOnStart: true,
      attachments: false,
      xoauth2,
      tlsOptions: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
```

I would also like to know search filters for outlook.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using LIST to list the mailboxes available to you?

Comment: @Max how to do that? I am using mail-listener-next package for IMAP connection.

Comment: Look in your API for the list command.  Or like, download Thunderbird and add it as an account and see what mailboxes you get.